High school algebra inequality question
I'm an adult who's trying to relearn high school math for my own betterment and I'm somewhat embarrassed to be taking up space and time on this forum with a very basic question such as this, but here goes.  I found this problem in an old high school algebra textbook:

The Municipal Parking Garage charges \$1.50 for the first hour and \$0.50 for each additional hour. For how many hours can you park your car if the most you pay is \$4.50?

I tried setting it up this way: $1.5 + 0.5x \le 4.5$
and solving for $x$ get an answer of 6.  But by making a chart to check my work, I find that the correct answer is 7.  Any input on how to correctly set up the inequality to get the right answer would be greatly appreciated.

If $n$ is the number of hours then the equation is $1.5+0.5(n-1) \le 4.5$. Your $x$ is the number of additional hours.

No need to feel embarrassed. This is a well written question about an extremely important skill (correctly interpreting the variables in an equation/inequality), and the answers will help a lot of people.

You need to clearly define your variables.  In this case $x$ is the number of hours after the first hour so you need to add $1$ to get the answer that is requested.  I found it useful to write down the definition of variables, because it made me think about what they really were.

This is correct, but might still be ambiguous for the OP. The inequality should be adjusted to $1.5 + 0.5(x - 1) \leq 4.5$. In this way, for the first hour, the $0.5$ term contributes nothing since $0.5(1-1) = 0$. All subsequent hours then have an additional $0.5$ term.

@AliasK:  It depends on how you define $x$, which is the point I am making.  Your change is correct if $x$ is the total number of hours parked.  The original inequality is correct if $x$ is the number of hours after the first.  I was working with the inequality presented.  OP did not define $x$, which is exactly the point of my answer.

And on a similar tone, one also needs to read the questions carefully to avoid simple gotchas. (That's more important when going to exams, which they might not be, but anyway.) Missing the word "additional" there might cause that off-by-one error, and the same cost structure could be given as something like "$1.00 at the start of parking, plus $0.50 for each hour". (Though I'll leave to everyone to decide if that's clearer or less clear in practice.)

But the inequality presented was not part of the problem statement - it was what the OP came up with. I always find it clearer, and less error prone, to have variables that directly correspond to the quantities in question. Since the question asked about total hours, I'd let $x$ represent that, and modify the inequality. And in fact that's exactly what the OP asked for help in doing.
